# How to configure a User before creating a database?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I would like my code to be FIPS compliant but the default username and passwords in Orient 2.2.13 are not. I tried specifying the user name and password when I get an OrientGraphFactory but that didn't fix the problem. I'm trying to log on as admin with my own 16 char password but it looks like Orient reverts to using admin : admin.

How can I configure a user before the database is created to make OrientDB FIPS compliant?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a user through the config/orientdb-server-config.xml configuration file, in the `<users>` element, like below:

```
  <users>
        <user name="root" password="{PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256}55F3DEAE:DLJEJFDKY8:65536" resources="*" />
        <user name="guest" password="{PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256}B36E7993C961:C8C8B36F3:65536" resources="connect,server.listDatabases,server.dblist" />
    </users>
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Thanks but another developer in my office ended up solving this problem. This solution wouldn't work for us since we don't want passwords stored on a file. I forget the details of what that developer did but it was done programaticaly.